# why ob_start gzandler is throwing following error on browser?

Tags: php, caching

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Comment: Did you send the gzip http headers?

Answer (score 1):

Use a network monitor - something like Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to look through the exact bytes traveling between the client and the server, and you'll be able to troubleshoot the issue easier.

Comment: Indeed. Typically the problem here is that someone isn't sending the proper Content-Encoding header OR they're trying to write the gzip stream to the client manually and messing up the integrity of the stream in some way.

Answer (score 0):

From some of the comments on [the PHP doc page on `ob_start`](http://nl2.php.net/ob_start):

> Make sure the editor you use does not
>   add the UTF8/UTF16 BOM at the start of
>   the scripts if you want to use
>   ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
>
> If those three characters are present,
>   browsers like Firefox won't be able to
>   decode the pages

Knowing the apparent problem, I have yet to find an adequate solution.